# Stretch control inside ViewBox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, viewbox

I'm using ViewBox control to scale my forms in winstore application. I need stretch controls inside ViewBox but common HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" does not work

This is my code :

```
    <Viewbox Margin="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
       <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
...
```

This is result :

[image]

ViewBox is grey rectangle, Grid is selected (blue rectangle),
TextBoxes do not have set width.

Can you advise me, how to solve this? I dont want to set width explicitly.

Comment: As kmatyaszek said, you're not really showing enough XAML.  Seeing that you have your Margin set, and its wrapped in another grid, which might be wrapped in something like a StackPanel, etc., we will never be able to reproduce the problem; so you probably won't get your question answered until you give us more of the visual tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try set `Stretch` property to `Fill` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretch(v=vs.105).aspx)):

```
<Viewbox Margin="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Stretch="Fill">
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

Comment: probably it wont help, because I use a some external styles etc. But if I remove ViewBox, the Grid is stretched in common way